# Can I program in C# on a Mac?

Tags: c#, macos, unity-game-engine

I want to learn C# for Unity and my personal computer is a MacBook Air. Can I program in C# on a Mac?

Comment: investigate if mono will do the thing for you, that's the only way

Comment: @GrantWinney Mono MDK or Mono MRE?

Comment: You can even use Unity on your Macbook (if your graphics card is up to it).

Comment: UPDATE: [Unity game development with Visual Studio for Mac](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2017/05/10/unity-game-development-with-visual-studio-for-mac/). So now you don't merely have C#, you have Unity, as requested, running in VS mac!

Answer (score 40):

Your first option is Microsoft **[Visual Studio for Mac](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/mac/)** which was released in 2017. If you're used to VS ide then I suggested you download this.

If not then you can have a look into **[MonoDevelop](http://www.mono-project.com/)**. You can download from **[here](http://www.mono-project.com/download/)**

MRE = Mono Runtime Environment

MDK = Mono Development Kit.

MDK = MRE + Extra tools, libraries, .NET PCL (Portable Class Library) profiles, etc.

If you have an application that you want to run that needs Mono you can install just the MRE.

If you are doing development, writing C# applications, whilst you can sometimes get away with just having the MRE installed, you may hit some missing features such as not having the .NET PCL profiles. So I would install the MDK if you are doing development. **[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24871755/3793448)**

Comment: **Visual Studio for Mac** should be at the top of your answer. By far the easiest way to achieve this

Comment: @KolobCanyon Updated as per requested

Comment: UPDATE: [Unity game development with Visual Studio for Mac](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2017/05/10/unity-game-development-with-visual-studio-for-mac/). So now you don't merely have C#, you have Unity as OP desired, running in VS mac!

Answer (score 25):

Yes, it is. Microsoft has released [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/download) 2017. It works on Windows, Mac OS, and Linux; It is quite nice development text-editor. It works similar to the full-version, available on Windows - with a few draw-backs, and it will allow to write programs, as well as run and test them right on your Mac.

[Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/with-visual-studio-code) offer a quick getting started tutorial and a Hello World program out-of-the-box with the Visual Studio Code.

You will need to install a few dependencies, however. Which may sound kinda of obvious:

1. Visual Studio Code
2. [.Net Core SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core)
3. [C# extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.csharp) from the marketplace.

I had good luck getting started and Visual Studio got all of the dependencies for me; so I simply went into the program, opened the integrated terminal (View > Integrated Terminal) and ran the command `dotnet new console`, and boom, a few seconds later I had a ***Hello World*** program, written in C#, running on my MacBook Pro.

Comment: It took me literally couple of minutes getting everything working!:) Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help @Mar

Comment: But I still didn't understand how can I run the Program.cs file?

Comment: For ongoing development, Visual Studio for Mac (mentioned in another answer) probably makes the most sense. To quickly test-drive a code snippet, VS Code and the CLI work nicely - thanks! However, the above instructions seem a bit incomplete. I followed the instructions here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/with-visual-studio-code?pivots=dotnet-6-0

Answer (score 10):

There is now a [Visual Studio for Mac](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/visual-studio-mac/) available as a free community version as well as professional and enterprise versions by subscription.

JetBrains also has an IDE for C#, called [Rider](https://jetbrains.com/rider), that runs on the Mac. If you use IntelliJ or any of their other products you might like it - it feels better to me than MonoDevelop or Visual Studio for Mac. It is a commercial product but JetBrains offers [very generous license terms](https://www.jetbrains.com/rider/buy/#edition=discounts) (as in free) for students and open source projects. They also have a substantial discount for startups.

Answer (score 5):

It is possible, but you won't be able to use Microsoft's tools, you'll need to use a third-party program like Xamarin Studio (MonoDevelop).

**Edit**

at the time of this answer there wasn't a Microsoft tool/IDE that could be used for developing .net / C# programs on a Mac.  Now there are two:

1. [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com)
2. [Visual Studio for Mac](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/mac/)

Answer (score 2):

Note that while everyone mentions Mono and Xamarin, which you should absolutely look into for *C#* development, *Unity* works on Mac directly, [specifically](http://unity3d.com/unity/system-requirements) Mac OSX 10.6+

while both use the C# language, some of the paradigms espoused by Unity are a little different from standard C# development. I personally recommend learning both.

**ADDENDUM:** Note that MS has recently announced that they'll be moving the standard .NET implementation cross-platform, and are doing so with the help of the Mono team, so while there's currently a confusing dual set of tools, it'll be shifting away from this in the future

Answer (score 1):

It is entirely possible, if you install a version of Windows using Bootcamp you can switch between the two at start up and have the full functionality of both by installing Visual Studio on the Windows partition. Alternatively, you could use VMware such as Virtual Box and use Windows within your Mac OS.

Comment: This is completely unnecessary compared to Mono or Unity