# Why isn't indexOf working for me? (indexOf is culture aware and missing a string comparison argument)

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to use `IndexOf` as given in the example here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s(v=vs.110).aspx

If you scroll down it shows the example:

```
  string s1 = "ani\u00ADmal";
  string s2 = "animal";

  // Find the index of the soft hyphen.
  Console.WriteLine(s1.IndexOf("\u00AD"));
  Console.WriteLine(s2.IndexOf("\u00AD"));
```

I am trying to execute that from `Main(string[] args)` and I get the compilation error, `IndexOf` is culture aware and missing a string comparison argument." I have imported `using System;` and `using System.IO;` and I'm using Visual Studio on a Mac. Am I missing something?

EDIT: Alright, the explanation of the problem can be found under "remarks":

> This method performs a word (case-sensitive and culture-sensitive)
>   search using the current culture. The search begins at the first
>   character position of this instance and continues until the last
>   character position.
>
> Character sets include ignorable characters, which are characters that
>   are not considered when performing a linguistic or culture-sensitive
>   comparison. In a culture-sensitive search, if value contains an
>   ignorable character, the result is equivalent to searching with that
>   character removed. If value consists only of one or more ignorable
>   characters, theIndexOf(String) method always returns 0 (zero) to
>   indicate that the match is found at the beginning of the current
>   instance. In the following example, the IndexOf(String) method is used
>   to find three substrings (a soft hyphen (U+00AD), a soft hyphen
>   followed by "n", and a soft hyphen followed by "m") in two strings.
>   Only one of the strings contains a soft hyphen. If the example is run
>   on the .NET Framework 4 or later, in each case, because the soft
>   hyphen is an ignorable character, the result is the same as if the
>   soft hyphen had not been included in value. When searching for a soft
>   hyphen only, the method returns 0 (zero) to indicate that it has found
>   a match at the beginning of the string.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10941375/could-string-comparisons-really-differ-based-on-culture-when-the-string-is-guara This can help

Comment: That's not a C# compilation error, in fact, according to Google you're the only person in the world having that error. Do you have StyleCop or ReSharper running and/or are you interpreting or translating that error message?

Comment: I'm not familiar with StyleCop or ReSharper but I just tried in a Windows machine (".Net framework" project) and it works... hmm edit: I think I need this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28280082/can-i-program-c-sharp-on-a-mac

Comment: Just for reference, I was using an "other->.Net" c# project. Microsoft announced it had signed a definitive agreement to acquire Xamarin on February 24, 2016, and I don't think I will be able to write a Windows c# project on my machine (which is what I was trying to do) at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that the implementation of the .NET Framework you're using does not have that overload. Try using the [`IndexOf(string, StringComparison)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224425(v=vs.110).aspx) overload that it's suggesting by adding the string comparison:

```
string s1 = "ani\u00ADmal";
string s2 = "animal";

// Find the index of the soft hyphen.
Console.WriteLine(s1.IndexOf("\u00AD", StringComparison.CurrentCulture));
Console.WriteLine(s2.IndexOf("\u00AD", StringComparison.CurrentCulture));
```